# a problem with NUnit environment

Tags: unit-testing, nunit

I have a problem: if i run this test in NUnit ,it works

```
Board  board = new Board("ab", 12, 120,BoardType.OEM, BoardSide.DoubleSide);
Assert.NotNull(board);
```

but when i want to add another Assert statement as

```
Assert.AreEqual(board.SNR, "ab");
```

it runs, and the NUnit window  is immediately  closed. Why does it close automaticaly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Stackoverflow?** (no pun intended)

Seriously, have you tried to trace into `board.SNR`?
A stackoverflow might explain the closing of your NUnit window.

Comment: yes the mistake was in property: 
string SNR 
get 
{ return  SNR;  }  and the correct variant is {return snr; } (field)